# Powershell script failed to execute. See the Service Fabric Tools pane in the output

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm having trouble deploying a service onto a local cluster.

```
...

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.47
-------- Package: Project: Project succeeded, Time elapsed: 00:00:01.8640999 --------
3>Started executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
3>powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ". 'C:\repo\service\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1' -ApplicationPackagePath 'C:\repo\service\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'C:\repo\service\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml' -DeployOnly:$false -ApplicationParameter:@{} -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'VetoUpgrade' -OverwriteBehavior 'SameAppTypeAndVersion' -SkipPackageValidation:$false -ErrorAction Stop"
3>Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : The BuildLayout of the application in 
3>C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_269749895297\o40yhtdd.vi3\Debug is invalid. Code is missing 
3>for service Service.
3>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
3>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:163 char:38
3>+ ... tionSuccess = (Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $AppPkgPathToUse)
3>+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage], FabricImageBuilderValidati 
3>   onException
3>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestApplicationPackageErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestApplicationPackage
3> 
3>Finished executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
3>Time elapsed: 00:00:01.4326464
3>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The above error message says "...\Debug is invalid. Code is missing for service<>". How exactly do I fix this problem? What code is missing?

+I did attempt creating that file path just in case, only to find out that the filepath seems to be randomly generated. That filepath did not exist before. 
+I am running VSTS 2019 with admin privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the output of a [Powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/test-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps) named `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage`. It is reporting that your package layout has an issue:

> The BuildLayout of the application in {*folder*} is invalid. Code is
>   missing

You can run this script yourself to reproduce, and fix the package layout issue. Compare your package with a working package, to see where the issue is. Maybe one of your manifest files is missing a `CodePackage` [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-and-service-manifests)?